# Clicking on an icon to open and close the tooltip

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how you can open the tooltip by clicking on the icon as well as closing it. I've been looking at some of the discussion here, but none of them doesn't seem to work at my end. Here is what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<span class="info">
  <img alt="aImage" src="images/aImage.png" />
  <span style="display: none;" class="stuff">something something</span>
</span>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".info").tooltip({tooltipcontentclass:"stuff"})
});
```

For this, of course, this will only show the tooltip if the mouse is hovering over it and closes it if you hover it away. I know it's not much, but this is the best I can do here. Please let me know if there is a way for opening and closing it by clicking.

Comment: What jQuery plugin are you using for `.tooltip`?

Comment: You must be using a plugin. Please post which one you are using.

Comment: It's called the jquery tooltip plugin. I can't remember where I've gotten it, but I guess I shouldn't be using that. Is there any other plugins that I can use for it or anything I can do with this program?

Comment: look inside the file itself to find where it comes from and post link to docs. If plugin supports click whould be easy, otherwise will need to look for another one that does

Comment: Here is the link: http://www.webringideas.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/. Download tooltip.zip and go to ntip inside the js folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not even need a plugin for this. 
A little CSS and jQuery is enough:

```
$(function(){

  $(".info").click(function(){
    var left = $("img",this).offset().left + ($("img",this).width()/2) - ($(".tip", this).width()/2);
    $(".tip", this).toggle().css({"left":left});

  });

});
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/NPXaf/

Comment: No wait, actually, the only thing is that I want it to click on the icon again to close the tooltip. The one that you have right now can close the tooltip if I click anywhere.

Comment: Click again where? In the picture or div.tip?
In div: http://jsfiddle.net/NPXaf/1/

Comment: Clicking on the picture again

Comment: then you need only select the image, not the div.info because the tip is within the info also. http://jsfiddle.net/NPXaf/2/